# How to return a field from MSSQL based on the value of two other fields

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, database, t-sql

I'm a MySQL guy these days and have a .NET project that I'm working on and can't figure out how to dynamically generate and return a field(column) from a table, based on two fields in the table.

There are two fields bRentable and bRented in the Units table and I need to return a field called reserved if bRentable and bRented are equal to zero.

Here is the SQL I have so far

```
/* Units Query */
SELECT Units.UnitID, Units.dcWidth, Units.dcLength, Units.dcPushRate, 
       Units.dcStdRate, Units.UnitTypeID, UnitTypes.sTypeName, Units.bRentable     
FROM Units
INNER JOIN UnitTypes ON Units.UnitTypeID = UnitTypes.UnitTypeID
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to achieve. More explanation will help to understand your question.

Comment: Basically in my SQL query I need to check if bRentable = 0 and bRented = 0 and if so, then return a column bReserved = 1.

Comment: What `reserved` field would be equals to? Would it be returned, if condition `bRentable = 0 AND bRented = 0` is false?

Comment: Yes. but it doesn't exist in the table, it's a computed value from the two fields in the table bRentable and bRented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the following as another column to your select statement:

```
(cast case 
when (bRentable = 0 and bRented = 0) then 1 
else 0 
end as bit) as reserved
```

Edit: Updated based on OPs comment:

```
SELECT Units.UnitID, Units.dcWidth, Units.dcLength, Units.dcPushRate, 
       Units.dcStdRate, Units.UnitTypeID, UnitTypes.sTypeName, Units.bRentable,(cast case 
    when (bRentable = 0 and bRented = 0) then 1 
    else 0 
    end as bit) as reserved   
FROM Units
INNER JOIN UnitTypes ON Units.UnitTypeID = UnitTypes.UnitTypeID
```

Comment: Where in my query would this go?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Units.UnitID, Units.dcWidth, Units.dcLength, Units.dcPushRate, 
       Units.dcStdRate, Units.UnitTypeID, UnitTypes.sTypeName, Units.bRentable,
       CASE When (Units.bRentable = 0 and Units.bRented = 0) then 1 else 0 end as reserved
FROM Units
INNER JOIN UnitTypes ON Units.UnitTypeID = UnitTypes.UnitTypeID
```

After this query in your function or sproc,you can just check the values of the field reserved.If its 1 return.

Answer (score 0):

if you'd like a stored proc or user defined function, the below query will help.

```
DECLARE @Rentable BIT
DECLARE @Rented BIT
DECLARE @Reserved BIT

SELECT @Rentable = U.bRentable, @Rented = U.bRented
    FROM UNITS U INNER JOIN UnitTypes UT ON U.UnitTypeId = UT.UnitTypeId

IF(@Rentable = 0 AND @Rented = 0)
 BEGIN
    SET @Reserved = 0
 END
ELSE
 BEGIN
    SET @Reserved = 1
 END

RETURN @Reserved // OR SELECT @Reserved
```

Search for ADO.NET & using SqlCommand with parameters, you can pass SqlParameters after you frame the command with your query.

```
SqlCommand.Parameters.Add();
```